# Passing a Slim 3 Exception response to an Angular application

Tags: php, angular, validation, response, slim-3

I’m creating an authentication system that uses Slim 3 PHP on the back-end and Angular on the front-end. So far I’ve managed to have it so a user can fill out a form on the frontend and send a post request to the back-end to insert that data into a database table.

Angular Register Component:

```
this.Auth.postUserDetails(username, password).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data, 'is what we received from the backend:');
  });
```

Angular Authentication Service:

```
postUserDetails(username, password) {
    return this.http.post('/api/achievement-forum-api/src/public/register',
      {username, password});
  }
```

But on the back-end I have some form validation that produces some messages when say a password is less than 8 characters, which is in the form of a class that extends PHP’s LogicException class.

```
use Throwable;

class InvalidFormData extends \LogicException
{
    public function __construct($message = "Password must be at least 8 characters", $code = 0, Throwable $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

}
```

This InvalidFormData is thrown when validation fails in the constructor of the Password class which is where validation takes place for passwords:

```
public function __construct(string $tainted_password)
{
    $cleaned_password = filter_var($tainted_password, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if ($this->isTooShort($cleaned_password))
    throw new InvalidFormData();

    $this->password = $cleaned_password;
}
```

Then finally in the controller class we try to register a user but if we catch an InvalidFormData exception we extract the produced message.

```
public function registerUser($request, $response)
{
    $tainted_username = $request->getParsedBody()['username'];
    $tainted_password = $request->getParsedBody()['password'];

    try
    {
        $this->authenticationService->registerUser($tainted_username, $tainted_password);
    }

    catch(InvalidFormData $e)
    {
        var_dump($e→getMessage()); //shows the message in the browsers console
    }
}
```

**Question:**

What I would like to do is pass this message back to the Angular front-end and display it on the form so a user is able to see why they failed validation.

I’ve read through Slim 3’s response documentation but I’m not sure If I would have to send this message back as a Slim response, and if so how would I capture this within Angular? My first thought was I might need a get request within angular to get the message, but I’m sure there is a way to do it within the original post request.

I have read some of the Angular documentation and it seems I need to do something in the subscribe method but I’m not really sure what.

Hopefully someone could show me some some code examples of this process. How would I create a Slim 3 response containing the message and how might I capture this in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set in `src/routes.php`:

```
$app->post( '/api/achievement-forum-api/src/public/register', function( Request $request, Response $response, array $args ) {
    $body = $request->getParsedBody();
    // probably $body = [ "username" => "user name", "password" => "pass word" ]
    /* Do validation stuff here */
    /* Depending of your validation results, set $status = something like 0 or 1... */
    /* Depengind of your $status, set $message = "string to be displayed" */
    /* Need to return data? $data = [ ... ] */
    return $response->withJson( [ "status" => $status, "message" => $message, "data" => $data ] );
} );
```

The response layout was inspired on Instagram API (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

I have no contact with Angular for some years, but I think you have to do something like `postUserDetails( params, here ).map(res=> res.json())` or another "responseHandler" method from the version of Angular you're using.

I'm use to do it with `fetch API` (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or `axios` (https://github.com/axios/axios) in my projects